# How can I determine the GPG/PGP key ID from the RSA modulus?

Tags: rsa, public-key, pgp

According to http://www.pgp.net/pgpnet/pgp-faq/pgp-faq-keys.html#key-public-key-forgery, key ID is some lower bits sequence from the modulus (i.e. the $n$ variable):

> A PGP key ID is just the bottom 64 bits of the public modulus (but only the bottom 32 bits are displayed with pgp -kv).

I have a key pair. According to *pgpdump*, my key ID (i.e. `64b`) is the following one `0x6BA09C369E31148C`. According to *GPG*, my key ID (i.e. `32b`) is the following one: `0x9E31148C`. Well, this is just the last 32 bits from the `64b` key ID.

I'd like to see a relation to my public modulus. I haven't found any, even if I play with endianess.

The key id is also weird… if it was last `32b` (or `64b`) from the modulus, it should be an odd number (except if $p$ == $2$ || $q == 2$$, which is very unlikely).

However, when I search lower 32 bits in my modulus (dumped by *pgpdump*), I see `0x84cfe5c1`, which is far different from `0x9E31148C`:

```
RSA n(4096 bits) - c8 1a 2e 7d e5 22 84 5c 10 b9 02 3b 42 ff 09 4c 60 f9 8a ce 80 64 8a 95 6a 0e 53 23 a3 dc fb fb f5 96 c7 a2 de be a9 f0 c8 f8 d8 51 
6d e8 bc 64 13 16 5e 25 f9 4d 44 bc 51 ef 7f 97 b4 05 a3 d9 9e e3 58 ef 88 c1 bb e5 23 65 45 1b 99 7b 68 c1 e4 1a 7d bc fb 51 c1 41 d6 10 33 34 90 c3 91 5c 5b 
ae 48 63 4e 65 46 4e 35 8e 48 e6 85 e3 9b ff b2 4b e9 c6 aa f1 45 3f b8 b6 b5 be 56 f8 04 4e 1d 1a d4 78 4d 75 fa 5e aa 2d 6d dc 31 2b c8 28 db cb 10 34 1a 16 
2c fd e2 67 e7 1d 0b e6 cc 53 92 5d 85 40 57 5c 9f 23 bb af 75 d9 11 2b 4a a0 6c ef c4 50 85 eb 79 46 b2 f7 03 54 8a c9 15 c0 ac d8 d4 5a 7c 5e 37 5e cc f2 13 
8a 67 3c 1f 26 c5 f4 11 d0 38 19 9c 34 0f c0 3d e7 63 67 8e 3f 7d 82 2e b6 59 d3 da 74 61 68 1c 78 7b 4c ce c3 5a f0 18 8c 3b ab 3c 88 03 28 6b 93 f5 b9 eb eb 
44 51 a7 b8 34 08 e9 a7 fa 81 d3 af 3d a0 f7 fa 6b f9 fb 98 97 38 32 d1 1f e4 e7 1a 4d af e3 e9 87 f8 ca b1 10 91 e5 9c fc db 4b 2d 23 3a 3f c3 fc 1b fe 15 c1 
df ff a2 0e fb 51 fe c3 1c 67 26 f3 f3 9d 50 ff 8b a7 48 f4 57 1c e8 63 e9 1e 1b 4a 27 96 02 9c 06 5a 62 ed 99 80 02 13 b2 31 66 a8 ee 79 15 85 05 61 81 67 0f 
b7 c6 4e d9 5f 31 81 64 d7 16 13 a8 70 a5 26 6f dc c3 cd f7 d3 8a 3d ab 79 60 34 6d 4e 9b f7 ef 32 eb 65 75 63 f4 79 1c 43 a8 ae 64 53 fd 56 77 d4 df 68 1e b6 
05 b0 d1 1d 7c fc 10 5a a3 aa eb 90 90 a8 6d 15 a6 8c 03 85 97 7b 0f 15 fe 19 07 ff 12 ff 10 87 fe bb 85 7b d3 98 34 24 8e c0 cb 5f 9a 42 81 71 76 3c fc 2d fb 
55 40 98 56 b0 b6 bd 26 8d bd 66 86 9a b2 49 cf a8 0f 4d 3c ed 62 34 79 4f 98 bd 5c 73 dc e5 45 cf 3f e0 a6 4a 59 e2 09 84 cf e5 c1
```

Where is the mistake in understanding the Key ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the version of the GPG format. In V3 the Key ID it is indeed the bottom 64 bits of the modulus, but in V4 it's the bottom 64 bits of the key fingerprint, which in turn is the  "SHA-1 hash of the octet 0x99, followed by the two-octet packet length, followed by the entire Public-Key packet starting with the version field" according to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-71).

Comment: That seems correct, because my kwy fingerprint is 831A 3FAC 3F17 798A 4590  7186 6BA0 9C36 9E31 148C. Thank you very much. Extra thanks for the link to the documentation.

Comment: What are V3 and V4 of the GPG format? I assume V stands for version here. Do you have a link?

Comment: The RFC linked in the answer has all the info you need.